# Android Wear phantom permissions?

Tags: android

This is really weird. The mobile companion of my wear watch face is displaying permissions that I've never registered. I've only included the basic permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml required for a watch face, including a vibrate permission. Even when I remove every permission to test the output, this is what it shows:

[image]

I'm not sure if this matter, but I did include some outside help from my app from this fine gentleman which required me to add this to my gradle dependency:

```
compile 'me.denley.wearpreferenceactivity:wearpreferenceactivity:0.4.0'
```

The link to the set of classes I used is:
https://github.com/denley/WearPreferenceActivity

Here is a brief AndroidManifest.xml for my mobile module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.floralwatchface" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FloralMobileConfigActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">


            <intent-filter>
                <category    
android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any advice appreciated.

Edit:

```
Wear gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.floralwatchface"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'me.denley.wearpreferenceactivity:wearpreferenceactivity:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.3.0'
}
```

Mobile gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.floralwatchface"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Comment: Please include your `build.gradle` file with your Google Play services dependencies.

Comment: Make sure you're using only the [selective APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) you need such as `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0` to prevent extra permissions.

Comment: Oh wow ok. I was browsing a sample project on Github and found it to be 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.3.0'. Just like you said. I'll change it and post results.